# PHP - concatenate in recursive function

Tags: php, recursion

I have function like this:

```
function getTree($r, $html) {
            foreach ($r as $entry) {
                if (count($entry['children']) == 0) {
                        $html .= '<li>' . $entry['parent_entry_id'] . '</li>';
                    } else {
                        getTree($entry['children'], $html);
                    }
                    //var_dump($html);
                }
                return $html;
            }
```

If I call it like this

```
$html = '';
$dzoni = getTree($results, $html);
echo $dzoni;
```

E expect to get few list elements 
But I get empty string.
It is not problem with the data. If I var_dump them I get the result. But result does not concatenate all the time. It simply stops at some point.
var_dump example:

```
C:\wamp64\www\co_3\regular_view.php:72:string '<li>17</li>' 
C:\wamp64\www\co_3\regular_view.php:72:string '<li>17</li><li>18</li>' 
C:\wamp64\www\co_3\regular_view.php:72:string '<li>22</li>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you recurse, you need to use the return value instead of discarding it:

```
getTree($entry['children'], $html);
```

Should be something like:

```
$html = getTree($entry['children'], $html);
```